# What is chaincode's transaction count

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-explorer

This is what my network setup.

1. peer1.org1.example.com
2. peer1.org2.example.com
3. peer0.org1.example.com
4. peer0.org2.example.com
5. ca_peerOrg2
6. ca_peerOrg1
7. orderer.example.com

After instantiation of my chaincode, I am getting transaction count as 0 in chaincode's tab in [hyperledger fabric explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer). But It is 4 in dashboard and channel's tab. What is the reason? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Share explorer logs. No one can  help you without checking the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instantiation of the chaincode is a transaction itself. So for each one of the peers that you instantiate a chaincode you will have a transaction.